# What apt-get command package should I use to install MySQL Connector C++ for Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu

I'm looking for to compile my C++ code

```
 #include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
```

But when I install `MySQL C++ Connector 8` via

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Then I won't get any folder named `mysqlx` inside `/usr/include` in my Ubuntu distro.

I also tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn7v5
```

and no `xdevapi.h` was shown up inside the `/usr/include` folder.

**Qustion:**

What `apt-get` command package should I use to install the [MySQL C++ Connector](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/)?

Comment: @273K So I need to compile from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't have any package that have `mysqlx/xdevapi.h` in its path.

As for [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp/#download--install), you can download Connector/C++ 8.0.33 for Ubuntu from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Alternatively you can download and install Oracle MySQL APT Repository from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ and after that

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Comment: Great! Not it's working